# Integrating acceleration profile in R

Tags: r

I need to integrate an acceleration profile (i.e. a consecutive series of accelerations over short time periods, for example every 0.004 seconds) using R and am struggling to figure out how to do so. I know how to work out the area under a curve for a given two points using Simpson's rule, but I need to do this for a large series of data so that I have a velocity value that corresponds to each time interval. So basically I have two columns (time and acceleration) and need to work out what values would be in the third "velocity" column. Any advice on how to code this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because all of your time intervals are the same, you can simplify this considerably. Assume you have an acceration vector, accel and a time vector , ta.  (Naming chosen to avoid the `t` function.)

```
vel <- cumsum(a)/ (ta-ta[1])  # there are no 0 vector indices in R.
```

If you want to use the trapezoidal rule you can add 1/2 of `cumsum(diff(a))`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, this is extremely helpful!

Comment: @Simon : Your questions will eventually gain less and less attention if you don't "play by the rules" on this playground. I doubt that Adam Liss is particularly hungry for further points but at least you should upvote Apprentice Queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you use trapezoid formula, then

```
v[i+1] = v[i] + (t[i+1] - t[i])*(a[i+1] + a[i])/2
```

Suppose your data.frame is X with columns t, a, and v. I assume your first row has t=0 and a=0.  One way of doing this is

```
lena <- dim(X)[1] -1;
X$v[1] <- 0;   # I assume that initial velocity is zero.
for (i in 1:lena) {
   X$v[i+1] <- X$v[i] + (X$t[i+1] - X$t[i])*(X$a[i+1] + X$a[i])/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping a running total of acceleration × time.

In other words, each pair of (acceleration, time) values tells you the amount of acceleration that occurred for that duration,  which in turn tells you the *change* in velocity during that time.  Add all the changes to arrive at the overall velocity.

So you can write

```
 v[i+1] = v[i] + (a[i] * t[i])
```

where:

`i` = the i'th interval
`a[i]` = the acceleration during that interval
`t[i]` = the duration of the interval (perhaps always 0.004 sec?)
`v[i]` = the velocity at the end of the interval

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

library(pracma);

cumtrapz(a,t)# where a is acceleration vector and t is time interval or vector

Comment: Can you expand on this a little more? Otherwise it might be better served as a comment and not an answer.